# Custom menu in Word Add-In

Tags: ms-word, word-addins, word-2007

I have a very old .dot file with some macro and custom menu. Where I can find markup of this menu and commands assignment (clicking on menu items calls different functions from macro code). I tried to find this settings in "Customize ribbon" block but didn't find my menu there. I tried in Word 365 and Word 2010.
[image]

Comment: Prior to Word 2007, there was an interface for this, which corresponded to the `CommandBars` part of the VBA object model. There is no longer a UI interface for interacting with these customizations since the introduction of the Ribbon. All menu and toolbar customizations are automatically placed in the `Add-ins` tab of the Ribbon. What, more specifically, do you intend to do?

Comment: I need to add else one more menu item. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: There would be, using VBA code, but it would make more sense to change everything to Ribbon XML than trying to maintain the old technology. Giving you full instructions how to do either is beyond the scope of Stack Overflow (it would be "too broad"). But there is lots of information "out there" on how to do both...

Comment: But already existing ribbons were created not in VBA. I took a look at the code and there is nothing about tabs.

Comment: As mentioned in the first comment, before Word 2007 the user was able to do this in a dialog box. That interface is no longer available (unless you have Word 2003 or older, somewhere).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, it will be much easier and faster to rewrite the ribbon menu with something new and supportable by microsoft. For this purposes I used [this](https://www.ribboncreator2016.de/en/)  tool.